# Is it possible to change audio track using flutter / chewie for a m3u8 stream?

Tags: flutter, video-player

Is it possible to change audio track using flutter / chewie  for a m3u8 stream ?

I am looking at the chewie documentation. It mentions about subtitles but no documentation for audio tracks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried for a long time to use that type of file for streaming audio and video, and my conclusion is that as of today flutter, whether using chewie or the basic videoplayer, is not yet ready for the use of streaming technology.

If you see this topic is still open: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59437